# Getting all the classes in project and their packages from CodeRush extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, coderush

I've spent some time trying to find a way CodeRush could add using when it finds undeclared element that is in the fact class name with no using added. The solution suggested [in this answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883037/automatic-adition-of-using-in-coderush) ([Refactor_resolve](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/Refactor_Resolve)) does not work (bugged?).

In a process I found out that writing plug-ins for CodeRush is easy, so I decided to code this functionality myself (and share it). I'd only implement a `CodeProvider` (like in [this tutorial](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/07/23/code-providers-101-implementing-unimplemented-properties.aspx)). The only thinks I need to do the job are answers to this questions:

1. At the start up of my plugin I need
   to get a list (set, map, whatever) of
   all classes and their packages. This
   means all the classes(interfaces...)
   and their packages in project, and
   within all referenced libraries. And
   I also need to receive updated on
   this (when user adds reference,
   creates new class). **Can I get this from some CodeRush classes or maybe VS interface available from `CodeProvider` class?**
2. **How do I add created `CodeProvider` to the pop-up that is shown when user hovers over an Issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, it looks like Rory has fixed some bugs in the "Refactor_Resolver" plug-in and it works now. As for your questions here's a quick reply:

RE #1:

CodeRush has a built-in cache for all types, project references, etc that is built while the solution is parsing. But at the moment it is used internally and not exposed for plug-in devs, sorry. However, here are some useful APIs to get started with:

```
  // Using the source code cache...

  // gets the active Solution object
  SolutionElement activeSolution = CodeRush.Source.ActiveSolution;
  if (activeSolution == null)
    return;

  // iterate thought all projects in the solution
  foreach (ProjectElement project in activeSolution.AllProjects)
  {
    string assemblyName = project.AssemblyName;

    // iterate inside source code symbols cache...
    Hashtable projectSymbols = activeProject.ProjectSymbols;
    foreach (object item in projectSymbols.Values)
    {
      ITypeElement typeElement = item as ITypeElement;
      if (typeElement == null)
        continue;

      // TODO: ...
    }
  }
```

To get assembly references cache, use a ScopeManager (located in DevExpress.DXCore.MetaData.dll), e.g.

```
  IEnumerable<IMetaDataScope> allMetaDataScopes = ScopeManager.All;
  foreach (IMetaDataScope scope in allMetaDataScopes)
  {
    IAssemblyInfo assembly = scope.Assembly;
    if (assembly != null)
    {
      ITypeInfo[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
      for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
      {
        ITypeInfo typeInfo = types[i];
        if (typeInfo == null)
          continue;

        // TODO: ...
      }
    }
  }
```

RE #2: To add a CodeProvider to the pop-up set its "CodeIssueMessage" property to the name of the code issue to fix, e.g.

myCodeProvider.CodeIssueMessage = "Undeclared element";

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. Your code allows be to build plugin's internal cache when the plugin is loaded. Of cause it would be much simpler then the CodeRush's cache - it would only contain a `String` for each object(`Class`, `Interface`... ) that can be referenced from within project classes. However this may be long running task. It is suitable to run at the plugin start up but I cannot scan all available classes each time code provider is used. It would be nice if I could register to some events that informs me about new(or deleted) classes or references so I don't have to rescan.